# How to create global setup in Taurus/jmeter

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I want to create a setup scenario that runs once per test execution, creates dependencies for my tests and saves a reference to them in global properties. I can not find any examples of this.

As a more concrete example I want to load test my comment section. I want to create a single blog post then write a bunch of comments to the same blog post.  I want to do these comments concurrently across threads using execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vanilla JMeter you can consider using [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) which is designed for implementing the preconditions, the values which you need to define globally can be populated using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to keep them in memory or stored into external file(s) using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)

Once you come up with a proper JMeter .jmx script you should be able to [execute it using Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) and see [real-time results](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConsoleReporter/), define [pass/fail criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/), etc.